# Is three any way to use a require() like function inside an HTML file to render a nested HTML file?

Tags: html, node.js

I'm trying to use an HTML template as a frame, and want to load the content inside of it depending on the route.
I'm used to PHP, so I know the require($file) option embeded in the code so it will render the needed file inside of the template, so I'd like to know if there is any thing similar to it.

I've tried to search about it, but it isn't that clear. So I've thought in two options, the first one is to split the template in two parts, and put the file content in between these two when sending the response.

This is what I am aiming for in the main HTML file and be able to render it in the NodeJS response.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My App</h1>
    { require($file); }
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey and welcome to stack overflow!!! If u like an answer please consider upvoting and or accepting it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy way is to read the template (with some placeholders for the variable text) into a variable. Then read the text that you want to put into the placeholders into another variable. Then just replace the placeholders. Output the final string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/mustache to render templates in node - it includes partial HTML templates and should feel familiar to your PHP experience.

(Just to answer you question directly - no, HTML by itself is static, and with exception of `iframe`, there is no safe way to include partial HTML within another HTML page.)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the iframe HTML object to embed it inside your file

```
<iframe src="<source html file location>"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

No. There's no way to add a 'variable' in HTML since HTMl it static. You need a dynamic language for that such as:

- [mustache.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mustache)
- [handlebars.js](https://handlebarsjs.com/)
- [pug/jade](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html)

Or if you're feeling really passionate about web development, and you are willing to begin hating html, then you should defiantly check out:

- [react.js](https://reactjs.org/) **Personal Favorite**
- [angular](https://angular.io/)

Let me know if you have any questions!!